# Wrongly used "La cocinero" instead of "el cocinero"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género

I recently started a food joint with the name of 'La Cocinero', instead of 'El cocinero'. I realized it is wrong now but how offensive or wrong on the use of 'la cocinero'? It will cost me so much to change and of course it will make us unprofessional to keep if it doesn't make sense or offensive to Spanish speaking society.

How can I safe myself?

Answer (score 4):

Without changing anything there's not much you can do.  There are only a few cases were a mismatched gender could potentially be correct (for example, the city *Los Lunas* en New Mexico is so named for the Lunas *family*).

Another way is if it's from an implied but omitted main noun.  *La plaza del Cocinero* for example could eventually (maybe) get reduced down to *La Cocinero*.  Similarly something like *La danza del Cocinero* could eventually get reduced down, but it's a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

As it is, it makes no sense.

Grammatical gender is a very strong thing in Spanish, everything has a gender and everyone is extremely used to it.
I think you could compare it to the error in the phrase "many dog", since *many* denotes plurality but *dog* is singular, it is wrong. The same goes for grammatical gender.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I would assume it's some kind of wordplay... or that the owners didn't know better (pun intended :-)). Doesn't sound offensive to my native-spanish-speaking ears. It's not like getting something wrong will be BAD... ask google, for example. ;-) So.. my advice: Find some funny way to work around the (honest) mistake.